# PHP 508 (Loop Detected) when loading images from database

Tags: php, mysql, html

I've been trying to create my categories page that lists all the possible categories on my site. I use a database to store my list of categories and all of my images.

---

DATABASE STRUCTURE:

Table: categories

Columns: ID,  name, description, icon

Data: 1, Category, Category Description, http://example.com/icon.png

When using my loop to go through all of my categories and pull the image from the icon column.

---

I use these lines to create my categories:

```
<?php $categories = $core->cat(); foreach($categories as $key=>$val) { ?>
    <div class="col-md-6 matchHeight">
        <a href="<?php $core->_siteRoot;?>/categories/<?php echo $val['name']; ?>" style="color: black; text-decoration: none;">
        <div class="well m1 emp category">
            <div class="media">
                <div class="media-left media-middle">
                    <img class="media-object" src="<?php echo $val['icon']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $val['name']; ?> Category Picture" width="128">
                </div>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h1><?php echo $val['name']; ?></h1>
                    <p>
                        <?php echo $val['description']; ?>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </a>
     </div>
 <?php } ?>
```

Opening up Chrome Dev Tools, I read the console saying that there is a an error with the image attached:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 508 (Loop Detected)

I contacted the host to see if there was a resource limit, but they responded back saying there is none for the plan I was at.

**EDIT:**

I have a PHP image system to pull from my database which are blob objects

```
if(isset($_GET['q'])) {
$req = $core->picture($_GET['q']);
switch( explode('.', $req[0])[1] ) {
    case "gif":
        $ctype="image/gif"; break;
    case "png":
        $ctype="image/png"; break;
    case "jpeg":
    case "jpg":
        $ctype="image/jpeg"; break;
default:

}
header('Content-type: ' . $ctype);
print_r($req[1]);
}
```

Comment: I think you are missing an "echo" here:  <?php $core->_siteRoot;?>  - but I doubt that this is the solution to your question.

Comment: What shows var_dump($categories)?

Comment: sounds like you have a problem with the url of the icon and not a php problem. Can you access the icon directly over the adress bar?

Comment: Most likely a rewriting issue when the icon is requested.

Comment: @TomMettam Yes, I was missing the "echo", but yes that doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: @HonzaRydrych array(10) which I have 10 categories and they each have an array of the name description and icon. It dumps the entire array so yes.

Comment: @radicarl I have a PHP GET system in place for pulling images from Blob objects from the database. Yes I can access them from over the address bar

Comment: Do you use .htaccess rewriting? And if yes, what are the rewrite rules and where, in the folder structure, the particular files sits? The problem seems to be in your PHP image system - also would be nice to see example of exact string output of <?php echo $val['icon']; ?> of any category.